# AH00428: Apache is continously restarting itself exiting with status 255

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, ssl, apache-2.4, openssl

Does anyone have an idea why my Apache instance is constantly restarting itself?

I see the following errors in the logs:

[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2592:tid 420] **AH00428: Parent: child process 1976 exited with status 255 -- Restarting**.

```
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2592:tid 420] AH00428: Parent: child process 1976 exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2592:tid 420] AH00455: Apache/2.4.25 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.2j configured -- resuming normal operations
[core:notice] [pid 2592:tid 420] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Apache24'
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2592:tid 420] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2532
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2532:tid 340] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:  Screen captures showing mod_proxy module and mod_proxy being loaded from httpd.conf:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am not using PHP by the way.  I am wondering if this is related to SSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you error says:

"Faulting application path: C\Apache24/bin/httpd.exe"

"Faulting module path: C:\Apache24\modules\mod_proxy.so"

Are you sure they are there?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  Please see my recent edits to the post above showing mod_proxy being loaded.

Comment: @MotoDave452 , Looks like you are the only one having that issue  https://www.apachehaus.com/forum/index.php?topic=1457.0

Comment: So it looks like this is affecting Apache 2.4.25 and I need to download an update for my VC version?  I will give this a try and keep you updated.  This looks promising.

Comment: This looks to have worked for me!  After navigating to the above link, I was able to access an updated version of mod_proxy.so for my specific VC version and OS (x64-vc14).  I replaced my current mod_proxy.so module with the new module provided from the following URL: https://www.apachehaus.com/forum/index.php?topic=1458.0.  After replacing the old module and restarting Apache, it seems that the issue has been resolved.  Marking this answer as accepted!

Comment: @MotoDave452 Glad to have helped you!